# How can I view numbers as "millons" in pinescript v5?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading

I coded a indicator that find divergences between price and volume. In somewhere in the code I use this block to print volume:

```
volume_variable = volume
volume_ma_input = input.int(20, title = "Volume Moving Average Period")

plot(volume_variable, color = close>open ? color.new(color.green,50) : color.new(color.red,50), style = plot.style_columns)

plot(ta.sma(volume_variable,volume_ma_input), color = color.white)
```

but when I use this, the outputs looking like "1850252" and not "1.8MN" as could be seen in the image below. what should I add? thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `format.volume` in indicator parameters

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", format = format.volume)

volume_variable = volume
volume_ma_input = input.int(20, title = "Volume Moving Average Period")

plot(volume_variable, color = close>open ? color.new(color.green,50) : color.new(color.red,50), style = plot.style_columns)

plot(ta.sma(volume_variable,volume_ma_input), color = color.white)
```